# Gridview Header Freeze not working in Master Pages

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I need the gridview header to be freezed while scrolling. So i got a script which works in normal pages. But while using Master pages it acts like a normal grid which has a scroll. what should i change in the script to make it work in master pages.?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

            var GridId = "<%= GridView1.ClientID %>";
            var ScrollHeight = 300;
            window.onload = function () {
                var grid = document.getElementById(GridId);
                var gridWidth = grid.offsetWidth;
                var gridHeight = grid.offsetHeight;
                var headerCellWidths = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < grid.getElementsByTagName("TH").length; i++) {
                    headerCellWidths[i] = grid.getElementsByTagName("TH")[i].offsetWidth;
                }
                grid.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
                var parentDiv = grid.parentNode;

                var table = document.createElement("table");
                for (i = 0; i < grid.attributes.length; i++) {
                    if (grid.attributes[i].specified && grid.attributes[i].name != "id") {
                        table.setAttribute(grid.attributes[i].name, grid.attributes[i].value);
                    }
                }
                table.style.cssText = grid.style.cssText;
                table.style.width = gridWidth + "px";
                table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
                table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].appendChild(grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0]);
                var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("TH");

                var gridRow = grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
                for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                    var width;
                    if (headerCellWidths[i] > gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth) {
                        width = headerCellWidths[i];
                    }
                    else {
                        width = gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth;
                    }
                    cells[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
                    gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
                }
                parentDiv.removeChild(grid);

                var dummyHeader = document.createElement("div");
                dummyHeader.appendChild(table);
                parentDiv.appendChild(dummyHeader);
                var scrollableDiv = document.createElement("div");
                if (parseInt(gridHeight) > ScrollHeight) {
                    gridWidth = parseInt(gridWidth) + 17;
                }
                scrollableDiv.style.cssText = "overflow:auto;height:" + ScrollHeight + "px;width:" + gridWidth + "px";
                scrollableDiv.appendChild(grid);
                parentDiv.appendChild(scrollableDiv);
            }

    </script>


 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
            <Columns
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using JQuery. A little bit of changes in the above scripts done this. got the output.

// Put the below code in a .js file

```
 (function ($) {
        $.fn.Scrollable = function (options) {
            var defaults = {
                ScrollHeight: 300,
                Width: 0
            };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                var grid = $(this).get(0);
                var gridWidth = grid.offsetWidth;
                var headerCellWidths = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < grid.getElementsByTagName("TH").length; i++) {
                    headerCellWidths[i] = grid.getElementsByTagName("TH")[i].offsetWidth;
                }
                grid.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
                var parentDiv = grid.parentNode;

                var table = document.createElement("table");
                for (i = 0; i < grid.attributes.length; i++) {
                    if (grid.attributes[i].specified && grid.attributes[i].name != "id") {
                        table.setAttribute(grid.attributes[i].name, grid.attributes[i].value);
                    }
                }
                table.style.cssText = grid.style.cssText;
                table.style.width = gridWidth + "px";
                table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
                table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].appendChild(grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0]);
                var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("TH");

                var gridRow = grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
                for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                    var width;
                    if (headerCellWidths[i] > gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth) {
                        width = headerCellWidths[i];
                    }
                    else {
                        width = gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth;
                    }
                    cells[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
                    gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
                }
                parentDiv.removeChild(grid);

                var dummyHeader = document.createElement("div");
                dummyHeader.appendChild(table);
                parentDiv.appendChild(dummyHeader);
                if (options.Width > 0) {
                    gridWidth = options.Width;
                }
                var scrollableDiv = document.createElement("div");
                gridWidth = parseInt(gridWidth) + 17;
                scrollableDiv.style.cssText = "overflow:auto;height:" + options.ScrollHeight + "px;width:" + gridWidth + "px";            
                scrollableDiv.appendChild(grid);
                parentDiv.appendChild(scrollableDiv);
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

// Add this small piece of code in the page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=this.grdDisplay.ClientID %>').Scrollable();
        }
            )
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Modified the above code for multiple gridviews support.

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.Scrollable = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
        ScrollHeight: 300,
        Width: 0
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function (index) {
        var grid = $(this).get(index);
        var gridWidth = grid.offsetWidth;
        var gridHeight = grid.offsetHeight;
        var headerCellWidths = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < grid.getElementsByTagName("TH").length; i++) {
            headerCellWidths[i] = grid.getElementsByTagName("TH")[i].offsetWidth;
        }
        grid.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        var parentDiv = grid.parentNode;

        var table = document.createElement("table");
        for (i = 0; i < grid.attributes.length; i++) {
            if (grid.attributes[i].specified && grid.attributes[i].name != "id") {
                table.setAttribute(grid.attributes[i].name, grid.attributes[i].value);
            }
        }
        table.style.cssText = grid.style.cssText;
        table.style.width = gridWidth + "px";
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
        table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].appendChild(grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0]);
        var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("TH");

        var gridRow = grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            var width;
            if (headerCellWidths[i] > gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth) {
                width = headerCellWidths[i];
            }
            else {
                width = gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth;
            }
            cells[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
            gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
        }
        parentDiv.removeChild(grid);

        var dummyHeader = document.createElement("div");
        dummyHeader.appendChild(table);
        parentDiv.appendChild(dummyHeader);
        if (options.Width > 0) {
            gridWidth = options.Width;
        }
        var scrollableDiv = document.createElement("div");
        if (parseInt(gridHeight) > options.ScrollHeight) {
            gridWidth = parseInt(gridWidth) + 17;
        }
        scrollableDiv.style.cssText = "overflow:auto;height:" + options.ScrollHeight + "px;width:" + gridWidth + "px";
        scrollableDiv.appendChild(grid);
        parentDiv.appendChild(scrollableDiv);
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Add this code in the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>, #<%=GridView2.ClientID %>, #<%=GridView3.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 200
        });
    });
</script>
```